# Docker: error response from daemon: invalid mode: /tf

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to using docker and my objective is to bind mount a docker image to a file path on my host machine (shown in the below directory) so I can:

- Run a Jupyter Notebook instance without losing the data every time I end my terminal session
- Link my Jupyter Notebook to the same path where my training data resides

I have tried at looking at many threads on the topic to little avail. I run the command shown below and am using Linux Mint:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --gpus all -v "$(pwd):/media/hossamantarkorin/Laptop Data II/1- Educational/ML Training/Incident Detection/I75_I95 RITIS":"/tf" -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.0rc1-gpu-jupyter
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Hossam

Comment: That `-v` option mounts the current directory (`$(pwd)`), to a very long directory path starting with `/media` inside the container, with options `/tf` (three parts separated by colons).  Do you mean to mount one of the first two paths to `/tf` inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when docker is not running.

Try `sudo service docker start` before entering your command.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to provide an update on this. The easiest way to work on your local directory is to:

- Do a change directory to where you want to work
- Run your docker while bind mounting to your pwd:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --gpus all -v "$(pwd):/tf" -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.0rc1-gpu-jupyter
```